# Posting to Facebook from Sharekit

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios6, sharekit

I am newbie to sharekit. I am trying to post a simple text: @"Hello" to Facebook, but facing problems in doing so.. It leads me to the login page. I login and then it closes and comes back to the main screen. But when i check my timeline, it is not added..

My ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    UIButton *btn;
    IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) UIButton *btn;
- (IBAction)btnShareClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

My ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "SHK.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btn;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])
    {
        self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(btnShareClicked:)] ,
                             [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                             nil
                             ];
    }

    return self;
}


- (IBAction)btnShareClicked:(id)sender {
    NSString *text = @"Hello";

    SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:text];
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];


    // For Toolbar
    //[actionSheet showFromToolbar:toolbar];


    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}
@end
```

I have included the MessageUI,Security,SystemConfiguration frameworks... Need some guidance on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should try to Check whether you are using the updated `ShareKit` API in Your Application.if Not then Add That Updated One from The SHareKIt Sites.

[Here is Link for The ShareKit Site](http://getsharekit.com/install/)

Here Is the Code See,Called WhenEVer You want to share text Over the Facebook.

```
-(void)shareOnFacebook{
 SHKItem * ietm1= [[SHKItem alloc] init];
 [ietm1 setText:@"Hello"];

 SHKFacebook *shkFacebook = [[SHKFacebook alloc] init]
 [shkFacebook setSHKItem:item];
 }
//see whether you have these Classes in your `ShareKit`.
```

I hope it may Helpful to you.

Comment: firstly, when i started,  i downloaded the sharekit from the website you gave and these are working based on the latest sharekit codes..next i added you code, and it is giving me this error:No visible interface for SHKFacebook declares the selector setSHKItem.

Comment: @laksh do you have these class in your ShareKit API, If OS then you should use My Code Rather Than Your.

Comment: i have them under Sharekit->Sharers->Services->Facebook

Comment: @you need to call my code whenever you want to share some text over the Facebook. have you done the same. i am sure that would work ....

Comment: SHKItem * item= [[SHKItem alloc] init];
    [item setText:@"Hello"];
    [SHKFacebook shareItem:item]; I use this code in my btnShareClicked method, but it doesn't post to my Facebook timeline...

Comment: Dude @laksh i am using the same code bfor sharing text over to the Facebook and it's working....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19682/discussion-between-laksh-and-ios-deveoper)

Comment: hi what changes did u make to the files.. can tell me??