# Is Facebook secret key important to be included?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, sharing, sharekit

I am adding the sharing capability to my client's app using Sharekit. I know his appID but not sure of the Facebook Secret Key. My question is whether it is necessary to include the Facebook Secret Key. Can i do without it?

If so, all i need to do is to:

```
#define SHKFacebookUseSessionProxy  YES 
#define SHKFacebookKey         @"some value for the app id"
#define SHKFacebookSecret      @""
#define SHKFacebookSessionProxyURL  @""
```

Am i right? Besides, the Facebook Key refers to App Id right?

Need some guidance on this...

Comment: "Besides, the Facebook Key refers to App Id right?" - yes it does. Also, as far as I know, on iOS the app secret is unused, so you may ignore/omit it.

Comment: thanks...so i have done the shkconfig file correctly?

Comment: @Iaksh I think yes. But go ahead and try it out nevertheless.

Comment: thanks.. i need your help in another question on mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431432/posting-to-facebook-from-sharekit  Can have a look at it?

Comment: @Iaksh well, I've never used ShareKit...